# Need to move/centralize files from different servers to one location

Tags: batch-file, copy, move

Need to help with bat script to move files from different servers to one location.

This is what I put together but it is only creating the folder not actually moving any of the files. Is there a simpler way I can move the cfg files from the different servers to the BACKUP_LOCATION on Server1

```
@rem Script to backup and centralize the config files from all servers. 
@echo on

SET CURRDATE=%TEMP%\CURRDATE.TMP
DATE /T > %CURRDATE%

Set PARSEARG="eol=; tokens=1,2,3,4* delims=/, "
For /F %PARSEARG% %%i in (%CURRDATE%) Do SET YYYYMMDD=%%l%%j%%k


set BACKUP_LOCATION=F:\Config_Backup\Essbase
echo %BACKUP_LOCATION%
set LOG_FILE=Essbase_Config_%YYYYMMDD%.log
echo %LOG_FILE%

echo Server Date and Time > %BACKUP_LOCATION%\%LOG_FILE%
DATE /T >> %BACKUP_LOCATION%\%LOG_FILE%
TIME /T >> %BACKUP_LOCATION%\%LOG_FILE%
echo(   >> %BACKUP_LOCATION%\%LOG_FILE%

echo HostName >> %BACKUP_LOCATION%\%LOG_FILE%
hostname >> %BACKUP_LOCATION%\%LOG_FILE%
echo(   >> %BACKUP_LOCATION%\%LOG_FILE%

echo Start Copy of Config Files>> %BACKUP_LOCATION%\%LOG_FILE%

echo \\server1\d$\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\epmsystem_ESS1\EssbaseServer\essbaseserver1\bin\essbase.cfg %BACKUP_LOCATION%\server1_essbase_%YYYYMMDD%.cfg >> %BACKUP_LOCATION%\%LOG_FILE%
copy \\server1\d$\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\epmsystem_ESS1\EssbaseServer\essbaseserver1\bin\essbase.cfg %BACKUP_LOCATION%\server1_essbase_%YYYYMMDD%.cfg >> %BACKUP_LOCATION%\%LOG_FILE%

echo \\server2\d$\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\epmsystem_ESS2\EssbaseServer\essbaseserver1\bin\essbase.cfg %BACKUP_LOCATION%\server2_essbase_%YYYYMMDD%.cfg >> %BACKUP_LOCATION%\%LOG_FILE%
copy \\server2\d$\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\epmsystem_ESS2\EssbaseServer\essbaseserver1\bin\essbase.cfg %BACKUP_LOCATION%\server2_essbase_%YYYYMMDD%.cfg >> %BACKUP_LOCATION%\%LOG_FILE%

echo \\server3\d$\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\epmsystem_ESS3\EssbaseServer\essbaseserver1\bin\essbase.cfg %BACKUP_LOCATION%\server3_essbase_%YYYYMMDD%.cfg >> %BACKUP_LOCATION%\%LOG_FILE%
copy \\server3\d$\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\epmsystem_ESS3\EssbaseServer\essbaseserver1\bin\essbase.cfg %BACKUP_LOCATION%\server3_essbase_%YYYYMMDD%.cfg >> %BACKUP_LOCATION%\%LOG_FILE%

echo \\server4\d$\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\epmsystem_ESS4\EssbaseServer\essbaseserver1\bin\essbase.cfg %BACKUP_LOCATION%\server4_essbase_%YYYYMMDD%.cfg >> %BACKUP_LOCATION%\%LOG_FILE%
copy \\server4\d$\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\epmsystem_ESS4\EssbaseServer\essbaseserver1\bin\essbase.cfg %BACKUP_LOCATION%\server4_essbase_%YYYYMMDD%.cfg >> %BACKUP_LOCATION%\%LOG_FILE%

echo \\server5\d$\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\epmsystem_ESS5\EssbaseServer\essbaseserver1\bin\essbase.cfg %BACKUP_LOCATION%\server5_essbase_%YYYYMMDD%.cfg >> %BACKUP_LOCATION%\%LOG_FILE%
copy \\server5\d$\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\epmsystem_ESS5\EssbaseServer\essbaseserver1\bin\essbase.cfg %BACKUP_LOCATION%\server5_essbase_%YYYYMMDD%.cfg >> %BACKUP_LOCATION%\%LOG_FILE%


echo List of Backup File  >> %BACKUP_LOCATION%\%LOG_FILE%
echo DIR %BACKUP_LOCATION%\*.cfg >> %BACKUP_LOCATION%\%LOG_FILE%
DIR %BACKUP_LOCATION%\*.cfg >> %BACKUP_LOCATION%\%LOG_FILE%
echo(   >> %BACKUP_LOCATION%\%LOG_FILE%

echo MOVE %BACKUP_LOCATION%\*.cfg %BACKUP_LOCATION%\Backup >> %BACKUP_LOCATION%\%LOG_FILE%
MOVE %BACKUP_LOCATION%\*.cfg %BACKUP_LOCATION%\Backup >> %BACKUP_LOCATION%\%LOG_FILE%
echo(   >> %BACKUP_LOCATION%\%LOG_FILE%

Exit /B
```

Comment: So you have `echo` on which is a good troubleshooting step.  Are you running the batch file from a command prompt instead of using your mouse.  That way you can see what happens when the copy command executes.

Comment: You also mentioned that it is only creating a folder.  There is nothing in your code that would create a folder.